# Laravel Eloquent ORM: trouble with one-to-many using belongs_to()

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, table-relationships

I'm having trouble accessing a relationship in Laravel. Relevant to this question, I have two tables, `messages` and `users`.

The `messages` table looks like:

```
Messages: id, user_from, user_to, read, message, created_at, updated_at
```

The `users` table looks like:

```
Users: id, email, password, name, created_at, updated_at, bio, reputation, last_login_ip, last_seen, active
```

The `user_from` and `user_to` columns are both ints that correspond to the `id` of the user (primary key) that sent the message or who the message was sent to.

The relevant portion of my `Message` model looks like:

```
class Message extends Eloquent {

    //relationships
    public function user_from() {
        return $this->belongs_to('User', 'user_from');
    }

    public function user_to() {
        return $this->belongs_to('User', 'user_to');
    }
}
```

The relevant portion of my `User` model looks like:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    //relationships
    public function messages_from() {
        return $this->has_many('Message', 'user_from');
    }

    public function messages_to() {
        return $this->has_many('Message', 'user_to');
    }
}
```

In a view, I'm trying to access the user that wrote a message, writing code that looks like:

```
{{ $message->user_from->name }}
```

Which throws an error `Trying to get property of non-object` on that one line. I know the `$message` object is defined because all other properties except `user_from` and `user_to` are defined and print out perfectly. I've read through the documentation several times and I can't figure out what I have done wrong here... does anyone stick out to anyone? This seems like a textbook example but it doesn't work.

The way I've passed the data to the view is:

```
$messages = Message::where('user_to', '=', Auth::user()->id)->take(20)->get();
```

Comment: To clarify, this is Laravel 3.

Comment: So if you echo out $message->user_to do you get an id at least?  Cuz then you could just workaround it like this....echo (User::find($message->user_from)->name)  ....Although it would be nice to get the relationship working

Comment: Trying that right now. *Edit:* yes, echoing out `$message->user_from` gives me the ID of the user it's from. I guess just doesn't make the connection that this corresponds to a `User` model. Not ideal at all with the SQL query in the view, but trying the workaround now...

Comment: I can do some really ugly stuff at the beginning of the view doing `$message->user_from = User::find($message->user_from);` and `$message->user_to = User::find($message->user_to);` to define them correctly.. but there has to be a better way?

Comment: That seems like a lot of SQL overhead running the query each time (for each message, that is) especially if there are a lot of messages.

Comment: relationships is the better way, but Im at work right now, so I can't dive to deeply into why yours isnt working...hopefully someone else can :)

Comment: Co-developer is also currently at work (Facebook). Let's just wait...

Comment: If this is still unanswered when I get home, Ill give it a real try. :)

Comment: You're not calling a method, you're calling a property. Try `{{ $message->user_from()->name }}` - or `{{ $message->user_from()->get()->name }}` , etc.

Comment: @RobW that gave an altogether different error, an error with SQL. I tried that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the method names in the `Message` model `from_user()` and `to_user()` instead of `user_from()` and `user_to()` (and changing the view to correspond) fixes the problem completely. No other code was changed.

Laravel fetches the database field over the method name, when you specify a custom field (I think). Weird.